# EditBoxPreference() storing the value as an int instead a string

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android application that can easily back up files and folders to the users PC. One of the things I wanted to implement was allowing the client running on the Android device to change the port I will be sending the file to.

For this, I've created an EditTextPreference to store the value.

The code I'm using to get this value back is

```
port = prefs.getString("serverPort", "<unset>");
```

However, this returns a string and I need an int, so I tried to use

```
sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
```

But this crashes the Android application, with (I think) a number format exception.

Is there anyway I can explicitly store the value that is entered as an Integer to make it easier?

I tried to use the method

```
port = prefs.getInt(...);
```

but that didn't work either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Print the port value before you make it as Integer because if the port value is not in number it will not able to convert to int.. So check first..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take whatever is entered into your edit text and put it in an int.

```
int yourValue = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
```

Note that Integer.valueOf() will return a format exception if you put a String in it that doesn't have an integer value.

You can then use

```
prefsEdit.putInt("serverPort", yourValue);
prefsEdit.commit();
```

to save it to preferences. And this to retrieve it

```
int port = prefs.getInt("serverPort", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. The "Integer.valueOf" method was just what I needed. I had completely forgotten about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the port as `String` or `int` doesn't make a big difference. Either way you'll have to convert it.

Your app crashes, because it cannot convert `<unset>` to a number, that's where the `NumberFormatException` comes from.

**Solution:**
Catch the `NumberFormatException` and set `sendPort` to a default value.

```
port = prefs.getString("serverPort", "<unset>");
try {
  sendPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  sendPort = 1234;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense now. I guess it's too early in the morning for me. Thank you for explaining what my problem was.